# Jwplayer 7.0.3 with flash 18 not playing videos, while HTML is working fine

Tags: flash, jwplayer, jwplayer7

Although it works well ni html5 mode with mp4 files, the player does not play neither flv files in flash mode, nor mp4 files in flash mode. In Chrome (44.0.2403.157) nd Firefox (40.0.3), it's loading indefinitely.

What is even stranger is that the player from the jwplayer dashboard (https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/#/players/basic_setup) manages to play flv files when loading them from the console using the following call:

```
jwplayer(document.querySelector('.jwplayer')).load([{ file:'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/flv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.flv' }]);
```

Here's a jsfiddle showcasing the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/kLdmj42d/ (make sure you specify a license key)

Just toggle the comments on the mp4 and flv files to make sure it actually works with the mp4 file.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="player">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jwplayer.key = "";
jwplayer.defaults = {
  aspectratio: "16:9",
  autostart: false,
  controls: true,
  displaydescription: false,
  displaytitle: true,
  flashplayer: "//ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.0.3/jwplayer.flash.swf",
  height: 260,
  mute: false,
  ph: 1,
  //plugins: {"http://assets-jpcust.jwpsrv.com/player/6/6124956/ping.js": {"pixel": "http://content.jwplatform.com/ping.gif"}},
  primary: "html5",
  repeat: false,
  stagevideo: false,
  stretching: "uniform",
  width: "100%"
};

jwplayer(document.getElementById('player')).setup({
  file: 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/flv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.flv'
  //file: 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'
});
```

I also posted the issue on JwPlayer's website: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/14332602-jwplayer-7-3-with-flash-18-not-playing-videos

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, apparently, the JwPlayer flash player needs access to `window.jwplayer` to work.

But, obviously, when using AMD, `window.jwplayer` is never set.

Until there's a fix, the workaround is to set `window.jwplayer` in the app's code.

As for jsfiddle, as I said in a comment, it doesn't work because of a sandboxed iframe.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/14351203-jwplayer-7-3-with-flash-18-not-playing-videos?new=14351203

Comment: Yeah, I tested it with multiple versions to see if the issue still happened.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, while this doesn't work in the JS Fiddle, when I load the following on my local, everything works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.0.3/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">jwplayer.key = "YOUR_KEY";</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/flv/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.flv"
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because there's an iframe in jsfiddle?

Comment: I put the page in an iframe to test, no issues at all - <iframe width='500' height='500' src='page.html'></iframe>, page.html has the contents from above.

Comment: The weird thing is that in Chrome, there is no issue for me, but I do see the issue in Firefox, but only in the JS Fiddle.

Comment: Correction, in Chrome it buffers, in Firefox it displays an error with no playable sources found. Only in the fiddle though. Do you have the same issue when you run the player on your site?

Comment: I get the same issue with 6.12 as well in jsFiddle.

Comment: I had the "no playable sources found" in FF, but it was just because of Flash not being updated.

Comment: As for jsfiddle, seems like it's because the iframe is in sandbox mode. Try adding the sandbox mode in your test page (sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin") and you'll have the same issue.

Comment: It doesn't explain why it still doesn't work in my app though (no iframe, only http). I'm investigating.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with AMD modules. When I load jwplayer without AMD, it works. If I load it with AMD, it doesn't.

Comment: Found the issue (see my answer). Thanks for your help, Ethan.

Comment: Chrome only blocks with the swf domain doesn't match the page domain, so that might be what is going on.